# I can not connect to switch via SSH after bruteforce

Tags: ssh, hp-procurve

One of the operators has bruteforced HP ProCurve switch via SSH. I have connected to device via console cable and killed all SSH sessions. However, I can not still to connect to device via SSH. How can I resolve this problem without device reboot? Thank you.

```
[SSH] Logged in (password)

[SSH] ERROR: Received disconnect from 172.31.0.1 port 22:11:
Sorry, the maximum number of sessions are active.  Try again later.



[SSH] INFO: DISCONNECT
```

Comment: Are you sure that SSH port 22 is still open?

Comment: @M.Rostami
Yes. Where are no sessions on the device.

Comment: Did you use `kill <1-6>`? Have you tried disabling and re-enabling ssh (`[no] ip ssh`)? You can also try setting the timeout to the lowest possible value (`ip ssh timeout 5`).

Comment: Change the SSH port to another. As an example, port number 8765. Try to connect this port as an SSH client.

Comment: You really need to give use the (sanitized) device configuration so we can see what may be wrong.

Comment: There is a stale ssh connections. And because you probably didn't set timeout for that kind of sessions, they're will be opened forever. You can either connect via console and clean them or reload switch.

Comment: It is not help.

`[SSH] Logged in (password)

[SSH] ERROR: Received disconnect from 172.31.0.1 port 2222:11:
Sorry, the maximum number of sessions are active.  Try again later.

[SSH] INFO: DISCONNECT`

Comment: @Zac67 Yes, I did it, but the same result...

Comment: @AndreyProkhorov The inactive timeout has set. There is no active SSH sessions on switch. However, I can not to connect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebooted switch. SSH works now.

Comment: You might have caught a bug there, if neither killing all sessions, changing ports, de-/reactivating SSH, nor waiting for timeout helped.

Comment: @Zac67 The latest version of OS on switch. Probably need to downgrade...

Comment: It's doesn't need to be on that single version. I'd verify with HPE support.

Comment: What firmware were you running? I could try to replicate this issue to see if it's a firmware bug or something else.

Comment: @Stuggi K.15.06.0008

Comment: Cheers, I'll check the release notes during the weekend if I can find something interesting!

Answer (score 1):

Change SSH port to eg. 2222. Not 100% sure, but probably all current sessions will close/drop.

SSH key-based authentication can be leveraged to eliminate password brute force attempts. So that won't happen anymore, problem solved.

Comment: It is not help. :-(

`[SSH] Logged in (password)

[SSH] ERROR: Received disconnect from 172.31.0.1 port 2222:11:
Sorry, the maximum number of sessions are active.  Try again later.

[SSH] INFO: DISCONNECT`

Comment: If you have a web interface of your hosting you should change SSH port there. If SSH is the only way you can connect.. Bad luck. Keyboard & mouse... :(

Comment: I changed the SSH port, but the same result. I can to connect via console port directly. Web interface has disabled for security.